# cannot find symbol class DiskInfo and some other packages despite being present in SDK folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an activity in which i have imported `android.os.storage.DiskInfo` and some other packages. Android Studio gives errors when trying to make the project saying:
 `error: cannot find symbol class DiskInfo` 

 When i tried to resolve this problem i found out that all packages are present in folder `$SDK-HOME\sources\android-24\android\os\storage` but i don't know why Studio couldn't import them properly.
Is there anybody who have experienced problems in import and have solved it?
Thanks

p.s: i am using Android API 24

Comment: Which API Level are you targetting?

Comment: i am using API Level 24.

Comment: Then it has to work. Thoroughly check out your Manifest and your gradle files.

Comment: @KlingKlang It seems that some of java files inside Android API couldn't be used from Apps. Actually there are so many java files inside `$SDK-HOME\sources\android-24\android\os\storage` but google documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/package-summary) only mentions 3 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of @hide in android source code. Actually Android is not allowing developers to use some classes. A solution is to use modified SDK which contains hidden classes. you can find it here https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Answer (score -1):

Check out : TargetSdk version and support package version.

Comment: Please don't do this back and forth in Answers. Any information salient to the question should be in the question so the Q&A is stand-alone.